# Share Database Between Activity and Service

Tags: android, sqlite, file-upload, service, ipc

I'm creating an queued upload manager. With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11346410/420001) answer to my previous question's guidance, I'll be using a Service, to upload these images. It was recommended that I use a database to keep track of the successfully uploaded, and the pending files.

My initial research leads me to believe that I'll want to create a Bound Service, so I can update my UI once the photos have uploaded, as well as a Started Service, so it can run independent of my Activities that create it. It seems that I'll also need to start it in its own process via the `process=":something"` directive in the app manifest.

My question is, what would the best way of sharing an SQLite (unless there is a better way) database amongst the N activity clients and the uploader service?

I envision it working like this, in pseudo code:

```
// in an app
writeRecordToDb( . . . );

// start service
if( service doesn't exist )
{
  // start service, and bind
}

// in the service:
if( shared db has another row )
{
  doDownload( . . . );

  if( download worked )
  {
    notifyActivity();

    if( db has another row )
      doDownload( . . . );
  }
  else
  {
    retryDownload( . . . );
  }
}
```

Is this the correct way to go about this? I'm again attempting to circumvent the problem of having multiple Activity instances request photo uploads when there is little to no cellular signal. I've just finished reading though the Service and Bound Service docs, and I'm feeling good, but not great.

Comment: Further to the answers already posted, I see from the question you linked to that a deciding factor in the queuing mechanism is that of network connectivity. I use a `BroadcastReceiver` to 'listen' for changes in connectivity and couple it with an `IntentService`. My `Activities` send network requests to the `IntentService` and if there's no connectivity, it adds the request to a queue and terminates. Whenever the `BroadcastReceiver` receives a network 'connected' `Intent` it starts the `IntentService` which then processes anything previously queued.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My initial research leads me to believe that I'll want to create a Bound Service

I wouldn't.

> so I can update my UI once the photos have uploaded

You do not need to use the binding pattern to update the UI. You can:

- send a local broadcast using `LocalBroadcastManager` that the activity picks up, or
- invoke a `PendingIntent` supplied in an `Intent` extra on `startActivity()` by the activity, or
- give Square's [Otto event bus](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/07/otto.html) a try (looks interesting, but I haven't used it yet)
- etc.

> as well as a Started Service, so it can run independent of my Activities that create it

Which is why you should not bother with binding, as you do not need that, but you do need to start the service.

> My question is, what would the best way of sharing an SQLite (unless there is a better way) database amongst the N activity clients and the uploader service?

Option #1: Keep your `SQLiteOpenHelper` in a static data member

Option #2: Use a `ContentProvider` wrapper around your database

> Is this the correct way to go about this?

Using a database as a communications channel between components is akin to two next-door neighbors communicating with each other using a banner towed by a biplane. Yes, it works. However, it is slow and expensive.

(also, there's never a biplane when you need one, but I digress...)

If you wish to use a database as a backing store for pending downloads, in case there is some interruption (e.g., user powers down the device) and you wish to pick up those downloads later on, that's fine. However, the service will know what to download by the command you send to it via `startService()`.

Answer (score 3):

CommonsWare covers basically everything you need... but here is some code illustrating the two options just in case there is any confusion.

1. Keep your `SQLiteOpenHelper` in a static data member.

   ```
   public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
       private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;

       private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databaseName";
       private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tableName";
       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

       private Context mCxt;

       public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {
           /** 
            * use the application context as suggested by CommonsWare.
            * this will ensure that you dont accidentally leak an Activitys
            * context (see this article for more information: 
            * http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)
            */
           if (mInstance == null) {
               mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
           }
           return mInstance;
       }

       /**
        * constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
        * make call to static factory method "getInstance()" instead.
        */
       private DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
           super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
           this.mCtx = ctx;
       }
   }
   ```

   Then in your `Service`/`Activity`, keep a reference to your `DatabaseHelper` and call `getInstance()` on it.
2. Wrap the database in a `ContentProvider`. If you already have one implemented, then you can simply use

   ```
   mContext.getContentResolver().query(...);
   ```

   This works because `Activity` and `Service` both extend `Context` (which holds a reference to the `ContentResolver`).