# Android File Upload Queue with Cancellation support

Tags: android, asynchronous, upload, queue, cancellation

We are developing an Android application, where there is a need to upload several photos to our server in an asynchronous way. Consider that as soon as a picture is taken, it will start being uploaded. As soon as it has finished being uploaded, the next one (all of them will be placed in a queue) will start being uploaded.

However, it is also important to support cancellation functionality, meaning that the user can interact with the app in a way that will remove an image from the queue or even cancel a running upload.

After searching for possible solutions, we have come to the following possible scenarios:

1) Use an IntentService for the queue mechanism and implement our own logic inside it. However, there are some worries as to how easy it is going to be to support cancellation.

2) Use the SD card and a local database to store the files and a Service to check for new files. This has been described here:
[Android (or iOS) - Image Upload Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346279/android-or-ios-image-upload-queue)

3) Find a way to use the built-in Android DownloadManager for uploads (can it really be done?)

4) Use AsyncTask and isCancelled() function.

5) Or ideally find another built-in Android/Java mechanism to do all of the above in a seamless way.

Any ideas?